# why isn't nginx redirecting root requests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

I have a rails app that is 100% SSL and i am trying to get nginx to redirect all requests to https, I am not sure if a misconfiguration exists in rails or nginx.

config/environments/production.rb is set to:

```
config.force_ssl = true
```

attempt 1:

```
server {
  server_name 192.168.2.4;
  listen 80;
  listen 443 ssl;
  . . .
 }
```

attempt 2:

```
server {
  server_name 192.168.2.4;
  listen 80;
  return 301 https://192.168.2.4$request_uri;
}
server {
  server_name 192.168.2.4;
  listen 443 ssl;
  . . .
}
```

in both cases going http://192.168.2.4 will show the nginx welcome page, yet http://192.168.2.4/login will correctly redirect to https://192.168.2.4/login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `ssl on;`

to the `server { }` block.

You can also link to ssl certs via `ssl_certificate` and `ssl_certificate_key`.